# bash - summing the output of wordcount

Tags: bash, shell, sum

Scenario:

I have a bunch of VIPs. While doing an NSLOOKUP, the output generally returns an output with one public IP. In cases where the loadbalancer fails, the NSLOOKUP returns two public IPs. for such scenarios, I want to write a script.

Logic:

```
for i vip1 vip2 vip3; do nslookup $i | grep -v "<private IP> | grep 'Address:' | wc -l ; done
```

in an ideal scenario, the output will look like

```
1
1
1
```

If I could sum the output, it would say 3. If something goes wrong, the output will show a sum > 3. I was unable to sum in the above case. Please advice

Comment: Why not pipe the entire loop to `wc` instead of piping each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of summing, just count the matches in the entire loop. And use `grep -c` to do the match and count in one step.

```
for i in vip1 vip2 vip3
do
    nslookup "$i"
done | grep -v "<private IP>" | grep -c 'Address'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. even if I go with grep -c, it would still display the output like I had mentioned earlier since it is going into a for loop.

Comment: But I'm doing the `grep` outside the loop, so it counts the total, not the individual commands.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I jumped the gun there. That took care of my requirement. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo vip1 vip2 vip3 | xargs -n 1 nslookup | \
   awk '/Address/ && !/<private-ip>/ {s++} END{print s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it with `awk`:

```
user@host:~# cat blub | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
4
```

blub is a file with contents:

```
user@host:~# cat blub
1
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a sum you can substitute the command into arithmetic evaluation construct. If your pipeline produces an integer, then try using following loop:

```
for i in vip1 vip2 vip3; do
    ((sum += $(nslookup $i | .. rest of pipeline .. | wc -l)))
done
# .. do something with $sum ..
```

maybe not the most elegant look, but shall work